# Problems with BibTeX

Tags: biblatex, errors

I tried to start working with BibTex today and I ran into the following problem: My IDE is TeXStudio and it always returns the error message

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
>   The top-level auxiliary file: Test.aux
>
> I found no \citation commands---while reading file Test.aux
>   I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Test.aux
>
> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Test.aux
>
> (There were 3 error messages)

when I run the following TeX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{clrscode}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\bibliography{library.bib}  



\begin{document}

BLABLA

\nocite{Handbook}
\cite{Proofs_From_The_Book}
\nocite{Reciprocity_Laws}


\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

My bib file is named "library.bib" and I generated it with Mendeley. It looks like this (some dates are still wrong, this is just a draft):

```
Automatically generated by Mendeley Desktop 1.19.4
Any changes to this file will be lost if it is regenerated by Mendeley.

BibTeX export options can be customized via Options -> BibTeX in Mendeley Desktop

@book{Proofs_From_The_Book,
author = {Aigner, Martin and Ziegler, Gnter M},
edition = {4th},
isbn = {3642008550},
publisher = {Springer Publishing Company, Incorporated},
title = {{Proofs from THE BOOK}},
year = {2009}
}
@book{Handbook,
abstract = {Cryptography, in particular public-key cryptography, has emerged in the last 20 years as an important discipline that is not only the subject of an enormous amount of research, but provides the foundation for information security in many applications. Standards are emerging to meet the demands for cryptographic protection in most areas of data communications. Public-key cryptographic techniques are now in widespread use, especially in the financial services industry, in the public sector, and by individuals for their personal privacy, such as in electronic mail. This Handbook will serve as a valuable reference for the novice as well as for the expert who needs a wider scope of coverage within the area of cryptography. It is a necessary and timely guide for professionals who practice the art of cryptography. The Handbook of Applied Cryptography provides a treatment that is multifunctional: It serves as an introduction to the more practical aspects of both conventional and public-key cryptography It is a valuable source of the latest techniques and algorithms for the serious practitioner It provides an integrated treatment of the field, while still presenting each major topic as a self-contained unit It provides a mathematical treatment to accompany practical discussions It contains enough abstraction to be a valuable reference for theoreticians while containing enough detail to actually allow implementation of the algorithms discussed Now in its third printing, this is the definitive cryptography reference that the novice as well as experienced developers, designers, researchers, engineers, computer scientists, and mathematicians alike will use.},
address = {USA},
author = {Menezes, Alfred J. and {Van Oorschot}, Paul C. and Vanstone, Scott A.},
booktitle = {Handbook of Applied Cryptography},
doi = {10.5860/choice.34-4512},
edition = {1st},
isbn = {9781439821916},
issn = {0009-4978},
pages = {1--780},
publisher = {CRC Press, Inc.},
title = {{Handbook of applied cryptography}},
year = {1996}
}
@article{Reciprocity_Laws,
abstract = {1. The Genesis of Quadratic Reciprocity -- 2. Quadratic Number Fields -- 3. Cyclotomic Number Fields -- 4. Power Residues and Gauss Sums -- 5. Rational Reciprocity Laws -- 6. Quartic Reciprocity -- 7. Cubic Reciprocity -- 8. Eisenstein's Analytic Proofs -- 9. Octic Reciprocity -- 10. Gauss's Last Entry -- 11. Eisenstein Reciprocity.},
author = {Shiu, P. and Lemmermeyer, Franz},
doi = {10.2307/3620530},
issn = {00255572},
journal = {The Mathematical Gazette},
number = {502},
pages = {171},
title = {{Reciprocity Laws: From Euler to Eisenstein}},
volume = {85},
year = {2001}
}
```

I would be deeply thankful to you if you could explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are using `biblatex` which requires `biber` not `bibtex`.  See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib) for some explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I could solve my problem with the linked question.